# Disabling CORS in UWP WebView2

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, same-origin-policy, websecurity

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404822/how-to-disable-cors-in-wpf-webview2) one, except my application uses UWP and not WPF.

As such, I need the UWP Web View to be ran as if it was a browser ran with the `--disable-web-security` flag, in order to disable CORS.

I tried looking into some documentation [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2hostresourceaccesskind?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1264.42) but couldn't figure out a way to do it in UWP.

Thanks.

Comment: This is CORS [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), it was not handled by webview, you need to disable it within your server side  configuration or like angular  disable with proxy json file.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew CORS is a policy only enforced by browsers. If you disable your browser from enforcing it by running it with the --disable-web-security flag, you will be able to make cross origin requests without the server allowing the origin